# YouCompleteMe won't work with C++11

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

I have encounter a problem using YouCompleteMe plugin on Vim.

I am using macOS. Following the installation guideline, I install it with `--clang-completer` options. It works ok when I am writing C++03 codes. But when I add to some C++11 codes, the plugin start complaining.

After trying `:YcmDiags`, it shows bellow:

```
Work/spike/cpp/main.cpp|7 col 12 error| rvalue references are incompatible with C++98
Work/spike/cpp/main.cpp|18 col 10 error| rvalue references are incompatible with C++98
Work/spike/cpp/main.cpp|18 col 5 error| 'auto' type specifier is incompatible with C++98
```

So, it seems that YouCompleteMe did recognize C++11, but something is wrong about compiling options. I check the `.ycm_extra_config.py`, which contains this:

```
flags = [
'-Wall',
'-Wextra',
'-Werror',
'-Wc++98-compat',
'-Wno-long-long',
'-Wno-variadic-macros',
'-fexceptions',
'-DNDEBUG',
# You 100% do NOT need -DUSE_CLANG_COMPLETER in your flags; only the YCM
# source code needs it.
'-DUSE_CLANG_COMPLETER',
# THIS IS IMPORTANT! Without a "-std=<something>" flag, clang won't know which
# language to use when compiling headers. So it will guess. Badly. So C++
# headers will be compiled as C headers. You don't want that so ALWAYS specify
# a "-std=<something>".
# For a C project, you would set this to something like 'c99' instead of
# 'c++11'.
'-std=c++11',
# ...and the same thing goes for the magic -x option which specifies the
# language that the files to be compiled are written in. This is mostly
# relevant for c++ headers.
# For a C project, you would set this to 'c' instead of 'c++'.
'-x',
'c++',
'-isystem',
'../BoostParts',
'-isystem',
# This path will only work on OS X, but extra paths that don't exist are not
# harmful
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers',
'-isystem',
'../llvm/include',
'-isystem',
'../llvm/tools/clang/include',
'-I',
'.',
'-I',
'./ClangCompleter',
'-isystem',
'./tests/gmock/gtest',
'-isystem',
'./tests/gmock/gtest/include',
'-isystem',
'./tests/gmock',
'-isystem',
'./tests/gmock/include',
'-isystem',
'/usr/lib/c++/v1'
]
```

Well it is a default config from internet. But I see `-std=c++11` in it, why is it not working? Any help?

Comment: Your flags contain `-Wc++98-compat`. No points for guessing what that flag does.

Comment: Magic from Cubic! I try commenting `-Wc++98-compat`, and problem solved!